# Using Protovis with Django

Tags: django, protovis

I am trying to get Protovis working in my Django site. Here is my sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="protovis-r3.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript+protovis">
        new pv.Panel().width(150).height(150).anchor("center")
            .add(pv.Label)
            .text("Hello, world!")
        .root.render();
    </script>
    {{ object.name }}
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this file directly in firefox, a Protovis 'Hello World' image is displayed toguether with the string "{{ object.name }}".

But when accessing the .html file template from my Django server, I only see the {{ object.name }} (the object's name printed out).

I haven't found similar issues so far, catering to Protovis use in Django.
If anyone has gotten it working or know what I am doing wrong, please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked for the javascript file using `src="protovis-r3.2.js"`

When you look at the html file directly, your browser will look in the same directory as the .html file for a file called protovis-r3.2.js.

However, when you ask Django to serve this same page, it doesn't follow the same protocol.  See [this article](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for more information.

To get it to work:

- Move the protovis-r.32.js file to a new directory: `/path/to/my/django_site/static`  (where /path/to/my/django_site is the absolute path to the django app)
- Configure urls.py with the line:

`(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', 
  {'document_root': '/path/to/my/django_site/static'}),`

- Change the src attribute of the script tag in your html code to:

`src="/static/protovis-r3.2.js"`

Comment: thanks Max, I have been stuck in this problem for quite a while. =)